# Post method request Alamofire (responseObject)

Tags: ios, swift3, alamofire, objectmapper

I want to create Alamofire POST request 
but I get failure response , I dont know the error in mapping object or in the request

```
   func loginUser() {
        let URL = ..... + "/Login"
        let params2 = "{\"MobileNumber\":\"\(MobileNumber.text!)\"}"
        Alamofire.request(URL, method: .post, parameters: [:], encoding: params2, headers: [
            "Content-Type": "application/json"]).responseObject { (response: DataResponse<Login>) in
                if(response.result.isFailure){
                  print ("failure")
                    print (response.result.description)
                    return
                }
                else{
                    print(response.result)   // result of response serialization
                    self.LoginUser = response.result.value
                }

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are setting encoding property of the request method to your `param2` variable.

Try setting parameter to `param2` and update encoding to use `.default`:

```
Alamofire.request(URL, method: .post, parameters: param2, encoding: .default, headers: ...
```

Answer (score 0):

You did not pass proper values into required fields. Use the corrected version below hope it helps

```
    func loginUser() {
            let URL = ..... + "/Login"
            let params2: [String: Any] = ["MobileNumber" : "\(MobileNumber.text!)"]"
let header = ["Content-Type": "application/json"]
            Alamofire.request(URL, method: .post, parameters: params2, encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: header).responseObject { (response: DataResponse<Login>) in
                    if(response.result.isFailure){
                      print ("failure")
                        print (response.result.description)
                        return
                    }
                    else{
                        print(response.result)   // result of response serialization
                        self.LoginUser = response.result.value
                    }

            }
```

Comment: I have updated the answer. Your parameter type was wrong. Try that. If it works be sure to mark ask correct